# Sf2 Forms - $form->getData() returns an array instead of an instance while defaultOptions 'data_class' setted

Tags: forms, symfony

i'm facing a problem with a Symfony Form.

I'm specifying the data_class in the formType class as show below :

```
    <?php

namespace myCompany\myBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use myCompany\myBundle\Entity\someEntity;


class someType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //here my form builder. No problem there...
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'aNameForTheServiceToBeCalled';
    }

    public function setDefautOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'myCompany\myBundle\Entity\someEntity',
            'empty_data' => new someEntity()
        ));
    }
}
```

As this form is declared as a service, i call it this way from the controller :

```
$form=$this->createForm('aNameForTheServiceToBeCalled');
```

Then at some point i want to get the posted form data, so i do :

```
$data = $form->getData();
```

According to Symfony API documentation:

> public mixed getData() : 
>   returns the data in the format needed for the underlying object

So i'm expecting $data to be an instance of someEntity.

But apparently i'm wrong because as i'm trying to $em->persist($data); i recieve an error saying :

> EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given.

So apparently $data is an array, and an instance of someEntity.
Thx in advance for your help!

**-----------------------**
**NB.**
i know that instead of calling

```
$form=$this->createForm('aNameForTheServiceToBeCalled');
```

from my controller, i could do the following instead :

```
$someEntity = //... new instance of someEntity, or from a repository, or whatever someEntity managerslike service
$form=$this->createForm('aNameForTheServiceToBeCalled', $someEntity);
```

**but that's exactly what i dont want to do....**

Comment: why not  `->createForm('aNameForTheServiceToBeCalled', new SomeEntity());`

Comment: what does the array contain ?

Comment: why not ->createForm('aNameForTheServiceToBeCalled', new SomeEntity());  ->> because that's exactly what i'm trying to avoid

Comment: what does the array contain ? --> it contains all the form fields in the array('field_name' => 'field_value') way, as if the data_class hadnt been specified...

Comment: well the symfony2 doc says that if you provide the data_class attribute it will per default take a new instance if no is passed, so maybe the empty_data attr. is obsolete or causing weird behaviour

Comment: yes thats exactly my point, i am expecting an instance and i recieve an array. I tried without the 'empty_data' option for testing purpose but i got the same result. I will anyway need as this will allow to instanciate the class with constructor argument whereas the only data-class option instanciate it by calling the constructor without argument. So to sum up, with or without empty_data options, same result, $form->getData() still retruns an array instead of an instance

Comment: `'empty_data' => new someEntity`. do you have a typo? Where parenthesis are?

Comment: With or without parenthesis, same result, still recieving an array instead of an instance (edited the post to correct it tho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a typo :

```
 public function setDefautOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
```

should have been

```
 public function setDefau**l**tOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
```

L was missing...
On how wasting 2 hours for nothing...
Thx everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Great, that's it. **setDefaultOptions is required, but is deprecated** since Symfony 2.6 and to be removed from 3.0 in **favor of configureOptions**.

Here you are a tip that will allow you a smooth transition from Symfony 2.X to Symfony 3.0 and above:

```
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $this->configureOptions($resolver);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => YOUR_ENTITY_OR_MODEL_CLASS::class,
            'attr' => array(
                'id' => $this->getName()
            ),
            'custom_parameters' => [] // Set a Variable that will allow to pass custom parameters from a controller to the type
        ));
    }
```